# Splitting string into words in php

Tags: php

I need to split a string to array of words by using all the non alphabetic and numeric characters(including '_') as delimiter
my present code is here

```
$result= wordarray(preg_split("#[&,$'_.;:\s-*]# ", $data));
```

AS you can see it can't work for these characters

> )(@#+-*/=!~`/ \

Please help me by adding this characters to the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some of these characters have a special meaning if you use them in a regex. So you need to escape them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ^ as a not operator...

```
$result= preg_split("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", $data);
```